# What is wrong with this mysql stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I use the following mysql procedure,

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `allied`.`GetRegistrationData`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`allied`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetRegistrationData`()

BEGIN
 select aboutUsId,name from aboutus where isDeleted=0
 select ageId,name from age where isDeleted=0
 select desiredsetId,name from desiredsetting where isDeleted=0
 select disciplineId,name from discipline where isDeleted=0
 select employeementId,name from employeement where isDeleted=0
 select salutationId,name from salutation where isDeleted=0
 select timeId,name from timetocall where isDeleted=0
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

when i execute this i get an error,

```
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'select ageId,name from age where isDeleted=0
select desiredsetId,name from desir' at line 4
```

Any suggestion...

Comment: Don't the SELECT statements need a closing `;`?

Comment: @pekka can my stored procedure tuned to make it faster since there are multiple select statements..

Comment: Can you give us the result that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Daniel i am using a page which contains 7 dropdownlists so i have used this query to bind values to them...

Comment: Are you having performance problems? Because if you need to get data from 7 different tables, that is pretty much the way to go. However you might want to reconsider the design of your tables. It is not immediately evident how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missed the semicolons at the end of each `SELECT` line

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to terminate your `SELECT` statements with a semicolon, to fix that error.

Comment: @bala your current question is completely different from your original one. I think it would be appropriate to accept one of the answers given (maybe throw a coin :) and start a new one.